# Demonstrating expansion in using l3

Tags: expl3, expansion

One of the pleasures, when using the l3 layer, is one does not have to deal with `\expandafter` commands (well almost). A good understanding of expansion though and how the variants deal with it, is important. I made this demo to show expansion, using the various type of variants.

**I am looking for improvements and or alternative approaches, that can help newcomers understand expansion.**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:n {f,x}
\ttfamily
\def\one{a} \def\two{\one,b} \def\three{\one,\two, c}
V-type~~  \tl_to_str:V \three\\
v-type~~ \tl_to_str:v{ three }\\
c-type~~ \tl_to_str:c{ three }\\
e-type~~ \tl_to_str:e{ \three }\\
x-type~~ \tl_to_str:x{ \three }\\
n-type~~ \tl_to_str:n{ \three }\\
o-type~~ \tl_to_str:o{ \three }\\
f-type~~ \tl_to_str:f{ \three }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Separate `\tl_to_str:c` from the rest, it uses a different base type. Also use the base type of `\tl_to_str:c` (`\tl_to_str:N`).

Comment: Thanks Skillmon. Yes I missed the `\tl_to_str:N`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to demonstrate `V`/`v`, I would construct two parallel examples, one set using macros and one using registers - toks would be most similar. This will then show that `V`/`v` type expansion only considers the 'value', not the storage type, of 'variables'.

Comment: Yes my intention is to add further examples (separate from this bunch to demonstrate and expand on the behaviour.  I am also looking for a good demo in spirit similar to I have I have done to explain all the ` \exp_args:N`  variants there must be 100 in the manual. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have built-in toks in L3, so using `V`/`v` on them is undocumented behaviour, I guess. Better stick to the built-in types.

Comment: @yannisl `\exp_args:N...` should almost always not appear in hand-written code: use `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` instead. They are there for the one-off cases or low-level optimisation, and are auto-generated.

Comment: @Skillmon Er, there are toks, for example `\tex_everypar:D` and more importantly 2e constructs, plus the old `l3toks` (still in `l3leftovers`), and the design behaviour of `V` is to expand registers ...

Comment: Also I think, separate example for doubling of # in the cases that is needed.

Comment: @JosephWright `:D` is a happy macro, it doesn't have to deal with users. I'd not consider `l3leftovers` if I were to write an introduction to L3 expansion. And I'm not sure whether it's documented that `V` works on 2e constructs. The question here is not real behaviour, but documented behaviour for an introduction!